# how to Change the name of bar button dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rightbarbuttonitem

Can anyone please let me know how to convert the bar button item named as "save" to "update" in view controller while updating the data in table view controller.
I am using ios 9, xcode 7.3 and swift 2.2.

I am providing the sample code for the bar button.

```
@IBAction func save(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

//func Plus(sender: AnyObject) {

    if isUpdate == true{
        print("object id \(self.store?.objectID)")
        self.store?.sTitle = titlename.text
        self.store?.sNote = note.text
        //save.setTitle("my text here", forState: .Normal)
        let img = UIImage(named: "image.jpg")
        let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img!,1)
        self.store?.sImage = imgData
        do {
            try appdelegate.managedObjectContext.save()
            self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

    }else{
        //get the description of the entity
        let storeDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Store",inManagedObjectContext: appdelegate.managedObjectContext)

        //we create managed object to be inserted to core data
        let store = EventsandnotesStore(entity : storeDescription!,insertIntoManagedObjectContext:appdelegate.managedObjectContext)
        store.sTitle = titlename.text
        store.sNote = note.text

        let img = UIImage(named: "image.jpg")
        let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img!,1)

       store.sImage = imgData
        do {
            try appdelegate.managedObjectContext.save()
            self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change title like this in your `viewDidLoad`

```
if (isUpdate == true) {
    let item = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
    item?.title = "Update"
}
```

Comment: I tried it but got the error as bool?cannot be used as boolean

Comment: You have created your boolean with optional wrapping so either change your declaration of boolean  like this `var isUpdate = false`  or use  `== true` with your if condition.

Answer (score 2):

You could make this in the `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
if let item = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem {
      item.title = isUpdate ? "Update" : "Save"
}
```

Comment: I got the the error as but optional type"()" cannot be used as boolean

Comment: Declare your boolean as var isUpdate : Bool = false and retry